# awk -F command to print based on first matched pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I am using `awk -F` command to print next set of words if 2 strings matched immediately.

If one of the search key word is repeated  in variable, then it is taking last matched key pattern. But I want the first matched pattern.

**EDIT:** In below example, I need to search for `CREATE` and `TABLE` keyword which may present at any line or split by any words. whatever it is if there is a match of `CREATE & TABLE` keyword, print next elements as below.

```
a="Hello I have a CREATE set or multiset TABLE as TABLE (uid, cid, mid)"
echo "$a" | awk -F"CREATE.*TABLE" '{print $2}'
```

> ```
> returns: as (uid, cid,mid)
> ```

But Expected output is

> as TABLE (uid, cid, mid)

Comment: What if you add an space after "TABLE" in the -F? `awk -F"CREATE.*TABLE "` This way, it won't match the second one with `(`.

Comment: @fedorqui : i edited my question. space may come for 2nd one as well

Comment: Then you can use `-F"CREATE[ a-z]*TABLE"`.

Comment: @Jotne: Its not duplicate. fedorqui ,always asked me to create separate question if multiple scenarios come in same requirement

Comment: @fedorqui : what is the meaning of [a - z] inbetween ?

Comment: `CREATE[ a-z]*TABLE` means: match `CREATE` + `any number of spaces and lower case characters` + `TABLE`.

Comment: @fedorqui : i tried, Still no use

Comment: I wonder if you _learn_ anything out of the answers you get.

Comment: @fedorqui : thats not helping me. I am expecting it to consider the first match

Comment: What you are looking for is non-greedy matching, as provided e.g. by [Perl](http://www.perl.org) (in the extended regular expressions). I don't know if there is an awk doing this; but Perl has some sort of AWK simulation (haven't used it ever, plain Perl is more flexible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most tools when processing regexps look for the left-most longest matching string. In your case:

```
a="Hello I have a CREATE set TABLE as TABLE (uid, cid, mid)"
echo "$a" | awk -F"CREATE.*TABLE" '{print $2}'
```

since you have the word TABLE twice on the input line, the TABLE from your regexp will match the second so the result is the longest possible match. There is no way in awk to change that behavior for regexp matching, other tools may have options to let you ask for a shortest instead of longest match but awk does not.

What you MAY have meant to write instead is:

```
echo "$a" | awk -F'CREATE +[^ ]+ +TABLE' '{print $2}'
 as TABLE (uid, cid, mid)
```

Comment: You downvoted the answer because you can't find gawk??? Use another awk. Good grief.

Comment: i have multiple lines in $a variable. its not returning anything now

Comment: i may have `CREATE set or multiset TABLE` so, it will not work

Comment: If you want us to help you, at the very least update your question with some real, representative input and expected output and tell us anything that can or cannot come between the CREATE and TABLE occurrences you are interested in. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: I have updated my question with EDIT part. Please have a look

Comment: You just changed 1 sample for a different sample. You are missing the point of posting sample input - one sample does NOT provide enough information to help someone synthesize your requirements. Good luck with getting an answer to your question.

Comment: the file contains sensitive information. so provided sample data; Anyhow thanks for your answer and time

Comment: No-one is suggesting you post ACTUAL data from customers or whatever - just that you make up a few samples that show us the possible formats of your data. Unless the format itself is top secret and then there's no hope...